# Help evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{a^{k} - a^{k - x}}{bx}}$ without L'Hospital?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{a^{k} - a^{k - x}}{bx}}$ if $a$, $b$, and $k$ are positive real numbers.

For this attempt, let $L$ be the limit, if it exists. Then,
\begin{align*}L &\;=\; \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{(a^{k - x})(a^{x} - 1)}{bx}} \\ L &\;=\; \left[\lim_{x \to 0}a^{k - x}\right]\left[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1}{b x}\right]\end{align*}

The first factor approaches $a^{k}$ and the second factor approaches $\frac{0}{0}$. Is there a way to get the limit of the second factor without L'Hospital's rule?

---

Edit: I just found a similar problem which is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x}$ using table of values. Is there an algebraic way to solve this?

Comment: Can you recognize a derivative, maybe? Look at the function $f(x) = a^x =  e^{x \log a}$.

Comment: Wait, are you referring to $\log a$ as $\ln a$?

Comment: Yes, it's quite common in many areas of the world to use $\log$ for the natural logarithm.

Comment: In any case, by definition we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0)$$ so all you need is the derivative of $f$ at $0$ to conclude. And the derivative of $f$ is just $f'(x) = (\log a) e^{x\log a}$ (chain rule+derivative of the exponential).

Comment: See my comment above. What is the definition (in terms of limits) of $f'(0)$?

Comment: Oh, I got it now. It is the definition of the derivative. If I may ask, can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are left with computing the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{bx}\,.
$$
Since $b>0$ is a constant, it suffices to find
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-a^0}{x-0}\,,
$$
where we rewrote it in that way (on the RHS) to recognize a derivative at $0$. Namely, letting $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = a^x=e^{x\ln a}$, we have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-a^0}{x-0}
$$
which is the quantity we seek to determine. So all you need is the derivative of $f$ at $0$ to conclude. But the derivative of $f$ is just $f'(x) = (\ln a) e^{x\ln a}$ (chain rule+derivative of the exponential), so $\boxed{f'(0) = \ln a}$.

Comment: How do you know $b>0$?

Comment: Well, it's specified in the OP's question, @WindSoul. (But also, the proof only needs $b\neq 0$ anyways.)

Comment: Did you downvote because of that?

Comment: Yes. I have downvoted because your answer was instantly accepted as correct while i consider it confusing since you relate to positive b which is irrelevant.

Comment: OK. You do you, I guess.

Comment: @WindSoul We were discussing in the comment section, and I asked if they could post their comment as an answer as it solved the problem. Also, I stated that $b$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Of course. Only that in the accepted answer the sign of b appears of relevance which only casts doubt as to how the answer was accepted in first place

Comment: The downvote can stay, it doesn't really matter and we shouldn't pressure people. (I disagree with it, of course... But, well.)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out irrelevant constants with

$$\frac{a^{k}-a^{k-x}}{bx}=\frac{a^k}{b}\frac{1-e^{-x\log a}}{x}=\log a\frac{a^k}{b}\frac{1-e^{-x\log a}}{x\log a}.$$ The last factor is well-known to tend to $1$.

Comment: Why the $e$ in the second factor, though?

Comment: @soupless: post updated.

Comment: I don't like reading "well known" on Q&A sites. It's not well-known enough for me at least.

Comment: @infinitezero: if you read the question, you'll see that the OP is aware. This said, if L'Hospital is forbidden (and equivalently derivatives and Taylor), there is little you can do but take this limit for granted.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, SE's idea is to answer questions for a broader audience and not only the OP. Anyway, I'd still like to see the argument for the last factor. Surely, if it's so well known it didn't be difficult to add it.

Comment: @infinitezero: feel free to provide your definition of the exponential.

Comment: @infinitezero You can use a table of values but the accuracy may be compromised. "Surely, if it's so well known it didn't be difficult to add it"; I'm not sure about this, but I got confused because I still lack a little ingenuity, that is why I asked.