# Prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h -1}h =\ln a$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Prove that

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{a^h -1}h=\ln (a)$$

I was thinking to do $y = a^h - 1$, so $\frac{\ln(y+1)}{\ln(a)} = h$ and then I could do something like:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac y{ \frac{\ln(y+1)}{\ln(a)}} =\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{y\, \ln(a)}{ \ln(y+1)}$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Use  the definition of derivative.

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's rule? Or Taylor expansion?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4108039/888233).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = a^x$. The limit in question is $f'(0)$. But the *definition* of $a^x$ is $e^{x \log a}$, so $f'(x) = e^{x \log a} \log a$ by the chain rule, so $f'(0) = \log a$.

Comment: This is the most explicit answer!

Answer (score 0):

From here

$$\ldots=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{y\, \ln(a)}{ \ln(y+1)}$$

we can easily conclude without using derivatives by standard limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{ \ln(1+x)}x=1$ which can be obtained from the foundamental limit

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

by $x=\frac1n \to 0^+$

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e^{\frac{\log(1+x)}x}\to e \implies \frac{\log(1+x)}x\to 1$$

Answer (score -1):

This is my first time posting an answer so please offer constructive criticism on formatting.

So first try direct substitution: $\lim_{h\to0}(\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}) = \frac{a^{0}-1}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$

$\frac{0}{0}$ is something called an intermediate form and now that we have this intermediate form we should applying something called L'Hopital's rule where $\lim_{h\to0}(\frac{f(h)}{g(h)}) = \lim_{h\to0}(\frac{f'(h)}{g'(h)})$ if the first limit is an intermediate form.

So in your situation  $$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{\ln(a)a^{h}}{1}\right) = \ln(a)$$

Comment: It's called ```indeterminate form``` not ```intermediate```.

Comment: This doesn't work because in order to calculate the derivative of $a^h$ you need to calculate the limit in question, so the reasoning becomes cyclic.

Comment: Actually: l'Hopital is "circular" here.  If you do not know this limit, then you also do not know the derivative of $f(h)  = a^h$, since this limit is the definition of $f'(0)$.